# Как убрать лишние пробелы в реализации метода split() с помощью цикла?

Tags: python, for, split

#### Дана строка:

`sentence = 'My favourite tutor in academy'`

#### мой код:

```
sent_list = []    
word = ''
for i in range(len(sentence)):
    word += sentence[i]
    if sentence[i] == ' ' or i == len(sentence) - 1:
        sent_list.append(word[:i])
        word = ''
print(sent_list)
```

При распечатке списка sent_list все слова кроме крайних  получаются  с лишним пробелом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Починить ваш код можно, если заменить:

```
word += sentence[i]
```

Таким тернарным `if`, не дающим добавлять в `word` пробел:

```
word += sentence[i] if sentence[i] != ' ' else ''
```

Вывод:

```
['My', 'favourite', 'tutor', 'in', 'academy']
```

Можно и обычный `if` сделать:

```
if sentence[i] != ' ':
   word += sentence[i]
```

Но в этом случае будет подряд повторяться похожий `if` в коде, что не очень хорошо будет выглядеть.

P.S. Тернарный оператор `word += sentence[i] if sentence[i] != ' ' else ''` является "синтаксическим сахаром" для следующей конструкции:

```
if sentence[i] != ' '
    word += sentence[i]
else:
    word += ''
```

В данном примере в нём нет особого смысла (блок `else` тут ничего фактически не делает), но часто тернарный оператор бывает удобен и знать его нужно.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает! Поясните как понять принцип работы  `if sentence[i] != ' ' else '' ` ? ...если символ не равно пробелу или путой строке?

Comment: @Alexandr Дополнил ответ, хотя про тернарный оператор питона написано много где

Comment: Спасибо еще раз!